# Reusing Python requests session in serverless function - when/how this session should be closed?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, python-requests, google-cloud-functions, serverless

I have a serverless function running Python 3.9 (technically Function App on Azure, but I'll refer to GCP Cloud Function since I found better documentation).

My serverless function is using `requests.put` a lot.
I wanted to add a retry mechanism to the request, so I can use the `requests.Session()` with some custom HTTPAdapter. If I reuse this session I'll have a retry mechanism and I'll squeeze some performance.

So basically I want to maintain persistent connections instead of creating a new connection upon every function invocation, and I got to [this documentation of GCP Maintaining Persistent Connections](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/networking#maintaining_persistent_connections).

The code snippet attached there is:

```
import requests

# Create a global HTTP session (which provides connection pooling)
session = requests.Session()


def connection_pooling(request):
    """
    HTTP Cloud Function that uses a connection pool to make HTTP requests.
    Args:
        request (flask.Request): The request object.
        <http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Request>
    Returns:
        The response text, or any set of values that can be turned into a
        Response object using `make_response`
        <http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.make_response>.
    """

    # The URL to send the request to
    url = 'http://example.com'

    # Process the request
    response = session.get(url)
    response.raise_for_status()
    return 'Success!'
```

**My question is** - when and how this session will be closed? session is a context manager and I was expecting it to be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCP Cloud Functions will automatically clean up the `session` object once your function instance *itself* is turned down.

(The point of persistent connections is to maintain them across multiple sequential requests to that specific function instance.)

I *suspect* Azure Functions is similar, but don't quote me on that.